# Google Analytics SDK for Android v2 (Beta) setCustomVar()

Tags: android, google-analytics

As Google mentioned in [developers page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/migration) :

> Custom variables are not currently supported in version 2, and calls to **setCustomVar()** should be removed.

So I wanted to know what I have to do until supporting this method?

Answer (score 1):

CustomVar are being replaced by [CustomDimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/customdimsmets?hl=en) in SDK 2.0, as well as the upcoming Universal Analytics.
Now you are allowed to use 20 CustomDimensions in a standard GA account, instead of 5 Customvar in previous architecture.